# When to update your app in play store/app store after publishing?

Tags: android, kotlin

Is there any particular time period for the app in the play store to be updated  (considering the fact that the developer or the company owning the app in not bothered of the update as they are satisfied with their app). Is their any chances of the app being removed from the play store due to this.

Comment: What do you mean by when to update? can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

There is no particular time interval between updates for play store apps. How ever some users checks for the last updated date before downloading an app and if the app was last updated a long time ago, they might not download the app, because they may think that the developer has stopped supporting the app. And there is no such app that is completely bug free. if you have one, CONGRATZZZZ... During the initial stages of your apps release, ie; when the app is in versions 1,2... you should pay close attention to your playstore dashboard to see the metrics, provides a lot of valuable information regarding your app's performance in devices and in playstore, and make changes to your app and fix bugs if there is any, and publish new updates frequently,at that time your app update interval will be very short. you  See [this article](https://savvyapps.com/blog/how-often-should-you-update-your-app) for more info about app update intervals

Answer (score 1):

There is no particular time for give an update to the app on play store.
Whenever you add some new features and you have completed the testing phase then you can update your app.